# Finding limit of complicated functions without derivatives

Tags: limits

Here's a problem I need to solve:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (\sum_{k=1}^n {(2-\frac{1}{k})^k})^{1/n}$

And I need to do it without derivatives. It's really hard for me as I can't even guess a limit, and even if I did I would still have to prove it. Where to start when I have such a complicated expession in front of me? Any hints?

One more thing - it's a sequence so it's defined only for $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression can be estimated from below by using only the last summand, so it is at least $\bigl((2-\frac1n)^n\bigr)^{1/n}=2-\frac1n$. We conclude that the limit (if it exists) is $\ge 2$.
On the other hand, the expression is less than $(n2^n)^{1/n}=2\cdot\sqrt[n]n$ and as $\sqrt[n]n\to 1$, the limit is certinly $\le 2$. We conclude that the limit exists and equals $2$.